# How can I list all of the ways to sum a list of numbers to N, with repeats, in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of numbers, say, 
    `[2,4,5,6,7]`.

I want to list all of the unique ways these numbers can be made into a sum, `N`, with repeats.

For example, if `N` were 8.  Answers would be:

```
2+2+2+2
4+4
6+2
4+2+2
```

Order does not matter.

The closest I've got is the answer to this question:
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

```
# check if the partial sum is equals to target
if s == target: 
    print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
if s >= target:
    return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    n = numbers[i]
    remaining = numbers[i+1:]
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([3,9,8,4,5,7,10],15)

#Outputs:
#sum([3, 8, 4])=15
#sum([3, 5, 7])=15
#sum([8, 7])=15
#sum([5, 10])=15
```

How could I modify this to allow for repeats?

Comment: Let's see your code attempt

Comment: I guess `4+2+2` should also be a solution?

Comment: You need a combinaison of 2 numbers in a collection of 5. It's math, no Python.

Comment: This question falls really under algorithms. A DP solution will suffice.

Comment: Take a look at solutions for the [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). It’s very similar and solutions will likely give you an idea how to approach your problem.

Comment: I have made a couple of attempts, but they're trash.  The closest I got was the answer to a similar question, here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum

Comment: 4+2+2 is a solution

Comment: Yes, that linked question looks good to me. There is a one-line change in the accepted Python answer there that makes this work for repetitions. If you are having trouble with that, please clarify your question to explain *what exactly* you are having trouble with.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools

data = [itertools.product([2,4,5,6,7], repeat = i) for i in range(2, 5)]

new_data = [[b for b in i if sum(b) == 8] for i in data]

print(len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_data))))
```

Comment: This is brute force and very inefficient...